# External USB flash drive FAT32 intermittently unmounts itself and takes down the other mounts

Tags: linux, mount, mate

The USB flash drive is a [PATRIOT XT 32GB](https://www.patriotmemory.com/products/boost-xt-usb-3-2-flash-drive). I've had this for at least 5 years and it works perfectly on my old laptop, a [Dell Latitude E6430](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000126349/dell-latitude-e6430-visual-guide). The problem cropped up after I started using it on a [Dell Latitude E7320](https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/latitude-7320-laptop/spd/latitude-13-7320-2-in-1-laptop).

There appears to be a problem with `gvfsd` on Debian stable.  When I plug in my USB flash drive, seemingly randomly, the FAT32 partition on the drive will unmount itself. Once that happens, it also umounts the other partition on the same drive (which happens to be an ext4 partition). (Note that the default behavior (which I found no way to change) in `caja` is to dismount/eject *all* partitions on a drive when even a single partition is ejected.  So, it seems to be having this same behavior, even though I did not explicitly bring `caja` up nor did I eject any partition.)

If I kill all `gvfsd` associated processes, things work swimmingly when I explicitly mount the partitions.  So, clearly, `gvfsd` is at fault, but it may be in coordination with `caja` somehow.

The latest stable Debian versions of `gvfs` (and friends) and `caja` are installed.

One workaround is, as mentioned above, to kill `gvfsd`, which is a bit inconvenient since I have to explicitly mount the partitions.  The other workaround is to explicitly unmount the FAT32 partition and use only the ext4 partition.

Note that I *did* run `dosfsck` on the FAT32 and it came up clean.

I noticed that I also need to `killall -STOP gvfsd-computer` to get the umount-ing of the FAT32 to stick.  So, it may be a bug specific to `gvfsd-computer`.

Comment: It appears that it's not just the FAT32 partition that's failing; it's the entire USB drive.  I tried the same drive on an old computer and it works just fine.  However, that computer only has a USB2 interface, not a USB3.  Not sure if that matters.

It's possible that there's a problem with the USB driver in Linux.  Will try to do more testing.

Comment: If the drive is 5 years old, I think you might want to make funeral arrangements. And get its estate in order by copying all of the data you need off of it ASAP. I mean USB 2.0 is painfully slow, but at least if it can be read via USB 2.0 then you can recover data if you need to. My condolences to the USB flash drive.

Comment: I'm starting to agree.  It seems that USB2 does not reveal the problems, but USB3 does.  If I turn on [quirks](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=322899), it works better *until* it reaches the very end of the partition, at which point there are I/O errors.  (I tested this via `rsync`.)  Luckily, I have lots of back-ups of the data on there, so it's not a big loss, just a bit inconvenient.